# Type based on template argument value

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I currently have a template function something like this:

```
enum class MyEnum { ENUM_1, ENUM_2, ENUM_3 };

template<MyEnum e, typename T>
void func( int i )
{
    std::vector<T> someData = ......;
    T someValue;

    switch( e )
    {
        case ENUM_1:
            someValue += func1( someData );
            break;
        case ENUM_2:
            someValue += func2( someData );
            break;
        case ENUM_3:
            someValue += func3( someData );
            break;
    }
}
```

The type `T` is dependent on the value of `e`. I'd like to write this code like

```
template<MyEnum e>
void func( int i )
{
    if( e = MyEnum:ENUM_1 ) T = char;
    else T = float;

    std::vector<T> someData = ......;
    T someValue;

    switch( e )
    {
        case ENUM_1:
            someValue += func1( someData, ..... );
            break;
        case ENUM_2:
            someValue += func2( someData, ..... );
            break;
        case ENUM_3:
            someValue += func3( someData, ..... );
            break;
    }
}
```

I can see how to make a type dependent on another type, e.g.

```
typedef std::conditional<std::is_same<T1, float>::value, char, float>::type T;
```

but can't figure out how to extend this to cope with enum values. Is it possible to do what I want to? If so, how?

Note: `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are fixed and beyond my control.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `std::conditional<(e == MyEnum::ENUM_1), char, float>`?

Comment: Nothing at all :) I just didn't realize I could do that with std::conditional. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. The switch is redundant (`e` is known at compile time) and limiting (all cases must be valid, for any template instantiation), not to mention `i` is unused. This is not the best way to go IMO.

Comment: Ignoring the `i` being unused, what could be a better way to go? I rely on `e` being compile time known so the compiler can optimize out the switch. The actual function is rather large with only small bits like in the example that change depending on `e` so specializing the template on `e` would lead to lots of code duplication. The helper function mentioned in an answer below factors out the switch but, to my mind, leaves the code less readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first template parameter for `std::conditional` is just a plain old `bool`, so you can just shove your logic in there:

```
using T = typename std::conditional<(e == MyEnum::ENUM_1), char, float>::type;
using T = std::conditional_t<(e == MyEnum::ENUM_1), char, float>; //C++14
```

Answer (score 7):

As alternative to

```
using T = std::conditional_t<e == MyEnum::ENUM_1, char, float>;
```

You can create traits, something like:

```
template <MyEnum> struct helper_fun;

template <> struct helper_fun<MyEnum::ENUM_1>
{
    using type = char;
    static constexpr char (*f)(const std::vector<char>&) = &func1;
};

template <> struct helper_fun<MyEnum::ENUM_2>
{
    using type = float;
    static constexpr float (*f)(const std::vector<float>&) = &func2;
};
```

and then (no longer switch)

```
template<MyEnum e>
void func( int i )
{
    using T = typename helper_fun<e>::type;

    std::vector<T> someData = ......;
    T someValue;

    someValue += helper_fun<e>::f(someData, .....);
}
```

Comment: Just for reference, I didn't mark this one as the answer to my question as my question was about how to base a type on the value of a template parameter, rather than a question about how to factor the code in a different way. Useful to see though.